# Apache Mina SSHD server

Tags: java, apache, sshd

I have an issue running apache sshd server on different platforms: 
Beging run on windows, it sends \r\n to client, while on linux( solaris) it sends \n only, which causes client to display new lines without carriage return. How to make it consistent to send proper line delimiter misregarding platform it is running on?

Comment: what happens when you modify the system setting line.separator ?

Comment: yes, the line.separator property affects the sshd server output, but i do not think this workaround is valid for my setup (can break other things)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, ended up with wrapping server's printwriter with hardcoded println(), the issue was actually not in sshd itself.  Though command list  still looks different on solaris and windows, but it is not critical.